# FluentAssertions: Custom Double Comparer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, precision, mstest, fluent-assertions

I try to get started with FluentAssertions but quite soon I ran in a problem. I use it along with MSTest. The test below fails what shouldn´t happen (from my point of view).

```
[TestMethod]
        public void DoubleTest()
        {
            double temp1 = 0.1 - 0.025;
            double temp2 = 0.075;

            temp1.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(temp2, options => options.Using<double>
            (a => a.Subject.HasMinimalDifference(a.Expectation, 1)).WhenTypeIs<double>());
        }

public static bool HasMinimalDifference(double value1, double value2, int units)
   {
      long lValue1 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value1);
      long lValue2 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value2);

      // If the signs are different, return false except for +0 and -0.
      if ((lValue1 >> 63) != (lValue2 >> 63))
      {
         if (value1 == value2)
            return true;

         return false;
      }

      long diff = Math.Abs(lValue1 - lValue2);

      if (diff <= (long) units)
         return true;

      return false;
   }
```

[HasMinimalDifference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Double_Equals_System_Double_)

I did quite some research but my impression is that Fluent Assertions ignores a custom double comparer. Or is it just me? I really want to use a custom double comparer as this might get extended beyound the MS-example above in the future.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce -  [my attempt](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c8oAsW)

Comment: Sorry, my bad @Guru. I forgot to mention I´m running on V4.19.4 at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things seems to be going on here.

1)
`Using` expects an action doing an assertion.

`Using<TProperty>(Action<IAssertionContext<TProperty>> action)`

You can workaround that by using `HasMinimalDifference(a.Subject, a.Expectation, 1).Should().BeTrue()`.

2)
Since you're using `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` you must be running v4.19.4 or older since we removed that method in v5.

I can reproduce the bug in v4.19.4.

You're hitting a bug where custom assertions were not applied on the root object.
The bug was fixed in https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/pull/1033 and released as part of v5.7.0.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void DoubleTest()
{
    object temp1 = 0.1 - 0.025;
    object temp2 = 0.075;

    temp1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(temp2, options => options
        .Using<double>(a => HasMinimalDifference(a.Subject, a.Expectation, 1).Should().BeTrue())
        .WhenTypeIs<double>());
}

public static bool HasMinimalDifference(double value1, double value2, int units)
{
    long lValue1 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value1);
    long lValue2 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value2);

    // If the signs are different, return false except for +0 and -0.
    if ((lValue1 >> 63) != (lValue2 >> 63))
    {
        if (value1 == value2)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    long diff = Math.Abs(lValue1 - lValue2);

    if (diff <= (long)units)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I haven't looked into what `HasMinimalDifference` computes, but here's the idiomatic way to perform a relaxed comparison for all doubles.
[Docs](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#equivalency-comparison-behavior)

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void DoubleTest()
{
    object temp1 = 0.1 - 0.025;
    object temp2 = 0.075;

    temp1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(temp2, options => options
        .Using<double>(a => a.Subject.Should().BeApproximately(a.Expectation, 1))
        .WhenTypeIs<double>());
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jonas, thanks a lot, this solved it and helped to better understand what´s going on in that case!

Comment: Hey Jonas, just a short follow-up: I tried to avoid 'BeApprox' because I´m not sure, what to put in as precision in a generic case. The 'HasMinimalDifference' compares the last significant bit so the difference between two doubles can be around this 16-orders of magnitude. 'double.Epsilon' as precision would fail the test, as its to small. See also: [C# goes math](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/08/c-math-gotchas/#:~:text=Epsilon%20in%20C%23%20is%20the%20same%20as%20DBL_EPSILON%20.)